# Clean way for inter-thread communication with select

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to implement a FUSE-driven filesystem in Python, which serves data from both local and remote sources. The filesystem is handled by the main FUSE thread: filesystem requests are dealt with straight as they're requested.

```
class MyFilesystem(Fuse):
    def read(self, path, size, offset):
        if self._isLocalFile(path):
            return self._localRead(path, size, offset)
        elif self._isRemoteFile(path):
            # get file from server
    # ...
```

I had thought to create a second thread on initialization which keeps the communication open between client and server. Commands flow both ways, so the client currently uses a select() call to wait for any incoming commands.

```
class CommsClient(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        conn = self._connect()
        while True:
            r, w, e = select.select([conn], [], [], 1.0)
            if conn in r:
                self._handleData(conn)
    # ...
```

The problem I have now is connecting the two threads. When the filesystem thread deals with a request, it might have to block until the comms thread returns a reply from the server. I think one way of accomplishing this is plugging a request stream/socket from the filesystem thread into the `select()` call, but I'm not sure whether sockets are best used for inter-thread communication. Shortening the `select()` timeout and checking for an Event or inter-thread variable would also work, I guess, but I'd like the mechanism to be as fast as possible.

Does anyone know the best way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using sockets for inter-thread communication is perfectly acceptable, but it will be slower than implementing it with threads and locks using in-memory data structures.
Notice that 'slower' is relative: Hard disk operations might still be slower by a tenfold.

Although it's not a direct answer to the question, may I recommend you look at
[ØMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/)? It's a very fast, It gives you 'sockets' that carry whole messages across various transports like in-process, inter-process, TCP, and multicast and it has asynchronous I/O.

Comment: Thanks! Reading the ØMQ documentation (very interesting stuff indeed) I came up with method using locks. Works better for now since I'd already implemented the client/server communication, but I'll definitely use ØMQ next time.

Answer (score 1):

Should anyone else benefit from it, the solution I used in the end involved using `threading.Event` locks and a non-blocking `select()` call:

```
class MyFilesystem(Fuse):
    def read(self, path, size, offset):
        if self._isLocalFile(path):
            return self._localRead(path, size, offset)
        elif self._isRemoteFile(path):
            # get file from server
            self.commsThread.requested_file = path
            self.commsThread.done_event.clear()
            self.commsThread.retrieved_file = None
            self.commsThread.request_event.set()

            self.commsThread.done_event.wait()

            return self.commsThread.retrieved_file[offset:offset+size]

class CommsClient(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        conn = self._connect()
        while True:
            self.request_event.wait(0.1)
            if self.request_event.is_set():

                conn.request_file(self.requested_file)

            r, w, e = select.select([conn], [], [], 0.0)

            if conn in r:
                self._handleData(conn)
                if self.retrieved_file:
                    self.done_event.set()
    # ...
```